# Usings xargs in Terminal with a bash script

Tags: command-line, bash

test.txt has four urls in it.

urls.sh: `cat test.txt | xargs -n 1`

check.sh uses command-line arguments for its url variable.

In Terminal, what do I write so that all the urls can be checked with check.sh using the urls.sh? Like if I say, ./check.sh http://www.cnn.com the bash script works perfectly.

I've tried:

```
./check.sh ./urls.sh
./check.sh | ./urls.sh
./urls.sh | ./check.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

```
xargs -n1 ./check.sh < test.txt
```

or

```
cat test.txt | xargs -n1 ./check.sh
```

should work if `check.sh` is in the current working folder (otherwise use the full path to `check.sh`, like `/usr/local/bin/check.sh`).